# I want to Sort the List but it Doesn't work

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a One Product Class:

```
       public class Product
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string email;

    public Product()
    {
    }

    public Product(string firstname, string lastname, string email)
    {
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Lastname = lastname;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get
        {
            return lastname;
        }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return email;
        }
        set
        {
            email = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string  GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return Firstname + sep + Lastname + sep + Email;
    }

}
```

I make a One more class where i am doing a ICompare

```
       public class PersonSort : IComparer<Product>
{
    public enum CompareType
    {
        Email
    }

    private CompareType compareType;

    public PersonSort(CompareType cType)
    {
        this.compareType = cType;
    }

    public int Compare(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
        if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");

        int result;
        switch (compareType)
        {
            case CompareType.Email:
                return x.Email.CompareTo(y.Email);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid Compare Type");
        }
    }
}
```

Then i call in ProductList Class

```
        List<Product> person;

          public void Sort()
    {
        person.Sort(new PersonSort(PersonSort.CompareType.Email));
    }
```

Then this method call in Form:

```
       private ProductList products = new ProductList();

           private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        products.Sort();
    }
```

but it show me null exception: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.****
Can you please help me.How to fix it?

Comment: What line does this happen on?  Is it possible one of your `Email` values is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<Product> person;`

Where is this given a value? You haven't included the code where you make `person`  a list and add items to it (or add items to a list and then assign it to `person`, etc.). A bug there could cause the issue.

```
public int Compare(Product x, Product y)
{
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
```

This is a bad idea, because it's part of the documentation of `IComparer<T>.Compare` that it is okay to pass in null, and null arguments evaluate as less than any other argument. While I don't think it is used with `List<T>.Sort()` it remains that methods that use comparers can depend upon passing in null being safe. Hence:

```
public int Compare(Product x, Product y)
{
   if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))//either both null or both the same instance
     return 0;
   if(x == null)
     return -1;
   if(y == null)
     return 1;
```

That could be related.

Finally, if an `Email` field was null it could throw at

```
return x.Email.CompareTo(y.Email)
```

Best thing to do is to have code in the constructor and setter so that it's impossible for that to ever happen. Delete the parameter-less constructor, add a null-check to the other constructor and to the checker so it throws `ArgumentNullException` when something creates a bogus `Product` rather than later on.

You can also add a check to the comparer:

```
if(x.Email == null || y.Email == null)
  throw new Exception("Cannot compare a user with null email");
```

Which won't fix the bug, but would help you track it down.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `null` reference somewhere. Make sure that the list is initialized. Also, is `Product.Email` properly set?

You may want to use `StringComparer` instead. Replace

```
return x.Email.CompareTo(y.Email);
```

with

```
return StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x.Email, y.Email);
```

Comment: How to pass the value in Email because its already in XML file and I am uploading that values in Listbox and then i want to sort that list?

Comment: @user1050667, sorry but I don't understand the setup you have. What XML file? Pass it where? What Listbox? Just open new questions asking specifically for single problems, and accept answers when they successfully address a specific topic.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided, `person` in `ProductList` is not initialized.  That being said, if you include the call stack of the exception in your question, you'll get a definitive answer.

```
List<Product> person;
```

to

```
List<Product> person = new List<Product>();
```

Comment: Does this resolve the NullReferenceException?  "still doesn't work" doesn't mean much to me here.